# ¿ Podemos llamar al utilisario para ayudar a la construcción en el constructor en C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

Quiero hacer un metodo que utilisemos cuando construimos un `Heap` (Montículo)
para hacer un estructura de datos del tipo árbol con información perteneciente a un conjunto ordenado. Quiero hacer un montículo minimo. Lo contrario son monticulos maximos : tienen la característica de que cada nodo padre tiene un valor mayor que el de cualquiera de sus nodos hijos :

[image: Monticulo maximo]

Quiero crearle de manera dinamica. Cuando utiliso el constructor llamo al utilisari para hacer el monticulo con `cout` y `cin`. Entonces hizo :

```
int main()
{

    int size;
    cout<<"enter no of elements of array\n"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    Heap* heap = new Heap(size);

}
```

Con la clase siguiente `heap.cpp` :

```
// array version
#include "heap.h"

using namespace std;

Heap::Heap(int size):size(size),array(new int[size])
{
    build_minheap(size);
}

Heap::~Heap()
{
    delete[] array;
}


void Heap::build_minheap(int i)
{   

    for(i=size/2;size>=1;i--)
    {
        cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
        min_heapify(int i);
    }

}

void Heap::min_heapify(int i)
{

    /*Cosas no importantes por lo momento*/

}
```

Cuando 
Tengo un problema con `Heap::build_minheap(int i)` pienso que no tenemos derecho a llamar al utilisario durante la construcion :

```
cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
min_heapify(int i);
```

El mensaje de error esta el siguiente :

```
heap.cpp: In member function ‘void Heap::build_minheap(int)’:
heap.cpp:22:3: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
   cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
   ^
heap.cpp:22:33: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
   cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
                                 ^
heap.cpp:23:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
   min_heapify(int i);
               ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Heap::build_minheap(int i)
{   
    for(i=size/2;size>=1;i--)
    {
        cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
        min_heapify(int i);
    }
}

void Heap::min_heapify(int i)
{
  /*Cosas no importantes por lo momento*/
}
```

Como ya te comenté en una duda anterior, con `nombre(tipo nombre)` no vas a llamar nunca a una función sino que estarías definiendo una función. La forma de llamar a la función  sería:

```
void Heap::build_minheap(int i)
{   
    for(i=size/2;size>=1;i--)
    {
        cout<<"enter element: "<<(i)<<endl;
        min_heapify(i);
    }
}
```

En cuanto al error que muestras de `cout`, en serio, debes aprender a leer y entender los mensajes de error. `cout`, como cualquier otra característica del estándar de C++, se encuentra bajo un espacio de nombres... en este caso `std`. Para poder usar una característica alojada en dicho espacio de nombres has de indicar dicho espacio de nombres y para ello C++ te da tres posibilidades:

1. Usar el espacio de nombres como prefijo en cada uso:

   ```
   std::cout << "test";
   ```
2. Importar el espacio de nombres completo:

   ```
   using namespace std;

   cout << "test";
   ```
3. Importar solo los elementos que nos interesan:

   ```
   using std::cout;

   cout << "test";
   ```

Todo esto asumiendo, claro está, que has hecho el `include` correspondiente.